# Polymer change in an element in a dom-repeat not reflected on parent array

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I have a really odd problem with polymer, these are the relevant pieces of code to explain it:

```
<dom-module is="...">
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{row.data}}" as="elem" index-as="col_no">
    <div class="entry">
        <div>[[elem]]</div>
        <input value="{{elem::input}}"></input>
    </div>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: '...',
    properties: {
        /**
        * It's an object like this:
        * {data: [1, "column2", "column3"] /* and other things relevant for other parts of the app*/}
        */
        row: { 
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
            reflectToAttribute: true
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

My problem is that, if I change the value on the inputs, it's all reflected nicely on the dom and I can see the result on the div too, but if I try to get the row property on other pieces of code (like say, even a simple `console.log(this.row)`), it still contains the original value.

I thought the `reflectToAttribute`thing would help but it didn't do anything different, I also tried adding an observer like this `observers: ['_test(row.data.*)']` but it was never called while editing the array elements with the inputs.

I think it might be because my array is inside an object and maybe that just messes up with how the data binding for dom-repeat does things, but I haven't found anything that actually confirms that.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your *data* is not part of the *row* object. Could it be that in your code you are referring to the data rather than row.data?

Here is the jsbin with console.log reflecting the changes in the row object - http://jsbin.com/nijixocaku/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: You know what, I tested my whole code on a clone of that jsbin and everything worked properly too... But when I test it on my own development enviroment I get the problem I mentioned on the question, any idea of why that happens?

Comment: @Alan - I don't know. It's possible that you are referencing earlier version of polymer that had a bug or something. jsbin example uses the latest version (which I believe is 1.0.8).

Comment: I ran bower update many times before this even happened (and after too) so I guess if anything it's a bug that a new version has that an older one doesn't, this whole thing is pretty weird because everything else related to polymer seems to run just fine